# web scraping for a hidden DIV only showing by click a button in the webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I need to scrape data from a website, there is a hidden div not showing until you click a button in the website. when I use code to get html content, I cannot get the hidden div content even if I can see the hidden div data in "Inspect"

Details of url, code and hidden DIV are as below:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://so.gushiwen.org/guwen/bookv_3694.aspx'
doc=requests.get(url)
print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(doc.text, "html.parser"))
```

[image]

Comment: IF you know 'selenium' or 'puppeteer' you can click the button and trigger hidden attribute so that you can get that div tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping hidden elements using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546766/scraping-hidden-elements-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selenium` to locate the desired `div` by id and use `soup.send_keys('\n')`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://so.gushiwen.org/guwen/bookv_3694.aspx')
d.find_element_by_id('right2321').send_keys('\n')
```

Now, you can use `BeautifulSoup` to scrape your desired content via:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
content = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('div', {'id':'right2321'}).text
```

Comment: run the above script, got error ``` ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable ```

Comment: I work it out: ``` d.get('https://so.gushiwen.org/guwen/bookv_966.aspx')
element = d.find_element_by_id('leftbtn784')
element.click()

hid = d.find_element_by_id('right784')

print(hid.text)  ```