# Scraping webpage with _ngcontent value within different html tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping and coding as well. So far I am able to scrape data using beautiful soup using below code:

```
sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_page, 'html.parser')
content = sub_soup.find('div',class_='detail-view-content')
print(content)
```

This works correct when tag and class are in format:

```
<div class="masthead-card masthead-hover">
```

But fail when format is with _ngcontent:

```
<span _ngcontent-ixr-c5="" class="btn-trailer-text">
or
<div _ngcontent-wak-c4="" class="col-md-6">
```

An example of _ngcontent webpage screenshot I am trying to scrape is below :
[image]

All I tried results in blank or 'None'. What am I missing.

Comment: How are you accessing the page? Likely this content is dynamically injected with JS. You'll probably have to hit the API by hand or use a webdriver.

Comment: @ggorlen I am using their site.xml and got the url from it. Thereafter using BS4 to scrap it.

Comment: @ggorlen You are correct, the html tags are changing every time I refresh. Now that's another trouble.

Comment: Does this solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546766/scraping-hidden-elements-using-beautifulsoup

Comment: html or .xml? I think you mean html. Try  `soup.select_one('.detail-view-title').split('|')[-1].strip()`  It would also help to see html examples of both types (including the text to extract)

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup runs faster than page loading.
so you should use Selenium library and ChromeDriver.

[here it is](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-web-scraping-in-python/)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29919386)