# how to get pagination data in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pagination

I am trying to get the data from this particular page - https://www.coworker.com/search/bengaluru/india

with beautiful soap. Since this page contains pagination ,the issue is that i am only getting data of first page only through beautiful soup and i want data of all the pagination pages. I checked the HTML part with inspect element but those href tag does not contains any link. anchor tag is calling some java script function to get the data of next pages.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium versus BeautifulSoup for web scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436014/selenium-versus-beautifulsoup-for-web-scraping)

You can also find many other answers by searching for [selenium requests python](http://selenium%20requests%20python).